# Find all numbers that have 30 factors and have 30 as one of their factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Find all numbers that have 30 factors and have 30 as one of their factors.
Thank you. 
Note: please show way if possible.

Comment: What have you tried?  You know $ord_p N ≥ 1$ at least for p = 2, 3, 5 ... that's a good start.

Comment: 30 prime factors? 30 factors of any kind? They are infinite, lol. It only condition is that $30 \mid n$.

Comment: No...there are only 6 possible numbers.  think about it...all you can do is to play with the exponents of 2, 3, and 5 and there aren't very many ways to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$ N= p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$$
then the number of its divisors is given by $(\alpha_1+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha_k+1)$. So, in order that $30\mid N$ and 
$ d(N)=30$ we must have $\{2,3,5\}\subseteq\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$ and $(\alpha_1+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha_k+1)=30.$ Now it is straightforward to check that the choice $k=3,p_1=1,p_2=2,p_3=5$ works as soon as $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}=\{1,2,4\}$, so:
$$ N = 2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5 = 720 $$
is a solution. I leave to you to prove that all the solutions are made that way, since there is a unique way to write $30$ as the product of at least three positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \in \mathbf N$. Writing the primefactor decomposition as 
$$ n = \prod_p p^{\alpha_p(n)}, $$
we know that $n$ has 
$$ \tau(n) = \prod_p \bigl(\alpha_p(n)+ 1\bigr) $$
divisors. (For any $p$ in a divisor we can choose $p$ appearing form $0$ to $\alpha_p(n)$ times), we have as $30 \mid n$, that $\alpha_p(n) \ge 1$, for $p \in \{2,3,5\}$. On the other hand, we must have that $2$, $3$ and $5$ appear in some $\alpha_p(n)+1$, as three of them are greater or equal to two, these must equal $2$, $3$ and $5$. So we are left with six possibilities
$$ 2^1 3^2 5^4, 2^1 3^4 5^2, 2^2 3^1 5^4, 2^2 3^4 5^1, 2^4 3^1 5^2, 2^4 3^2 5^1 $$

Answer (score 0):

We write the  number as $2^{1+a}3^{1+b}{5^{1+c}}n$ with $(n,30)=1$.

The number of divisors of the number is $30=(2+a)(2+b)(2+c)\tau(n)$. Hence $\tau(n)=1\implies n=1$ ($\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$).

So $2+a,2+b,2+c$ are $2,3,5$ in some order.

There are $6$ solutions:

$2\cdot3^2\cdot5^4=11250$

$2\cdot3^4\cdot5^2=4050$

$2^2\cdot3\cdot5^4=7500$

$2^2\cdot3^4\cdot5=1620$

$2^4\cdot3\cdot5^2=1200$

$2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5=720$